# Gradle: assembling multiple source-sets into one jar

Tags: java, gradle

I've asked a related question here [JOOQ class generation and gradle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27244262/jooq-class-generation-and-gradle)

In that question I'm trying to find the best way to do a multi-stage build including generating classes in a middle step. I've gone down the Option Two approach, and now find myself an impasse.

I have the following build.gradle file

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'

sourceSets
{
    bootstrap 

    generated {
        compileClasspath += bootstrap.output
    }

    main {
        compileClasspath += bootstrap.output
        compileClasspath += generated.output
    }
}

buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'org.jooq:jooq-codegen:3.5.0'
        classpath 'postgresql:postgresql:9.1-901.jdbc4'
        classpath project(":")
    }
}

dependencies
{
    compile 'org.jooq:jooq:3.5.0'
    compile 'org.jooq:jooq-codegen:3.5.0'
    compile 'org.apache.poi:poi:3.10.1'
    compile 'com.google.guava:guava:18.0'

    generatedCompile 'org.jooq:jooq:3.5.0'
    generatedCompile 'org.jooq:jooq-codegen:3.5.0'
    generatedCompile 'org.apache.poi:poi:3.10.1'
    generatedCompile 'com.google.guava:guava:18.0'

    bootstrapCompile 'org.jooq:jooq:3.5.0'
    bootstrapCompile 'org.jooq:jooq-codegen:3.5.0'
    bootstrapCompile 'org.apache.poi:poi:3.10.1'
    bootstrapCompile 'com.google.guava:guava:18.0'
}

task generate << {
    //Use JOOQ to generate classes, with the output going into the generated sourceSet
          .withDirectory(file("src/generated/java").getAbsolutePath())
}

generatedClasses
{
    dependsOn bootstrapClasses
    dependsOn generate
}

jar
{
    dependsOn generatedClasses
    dependsOn bootstrapClasses
}
```

The structure is that

- the **bootstrap** source set holds some core java classes that are required for the code generation, plus an sql file that will be used to pouplate a database
- The **generate** task uses the classes and sql file in **boostrap** to generate classes
- The **generated** source set holds the outputs of the generation task, and
- The **main** source set holds what might be called the "normal" classes (i.e. the ones that make use of the database being described by the bootstrap and generated classes)

I have a couple of problems, which I can't untangle:

1. I seem to have to duplicate the dependencies for each source-set
2. When the jar file gets built, it only contains the classes generated from the **main** source set

I should note that the build as it stands above will successfully generate each of the source-sets.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do You have an example online to try?

Comment: Hi Opal. I can put one together. I'll do that this evening.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

O.K. I think I have found the answer to this question. There were two parts....

The first problem, having to specify the same dependencies multiple times, was fixed by adding this:

```
configurations {
    generatedCompile {
        extendsFrom compile
    }
    bootstrapCompile { 
        extendsFrom compile
    }
}
```

The second problem, the jar file not having all the build artefacts, was fixed by changing the jar task to

```
jar 
{
    from sourceSets.generated.output
    from sourceSets.bootstrap.output
    dependsOn bootstrapClasses
    dependsOn generatedClasses
}
```

Comment: I think you don't actually need the `dependsOn` statements. Gradle should automatically detect the right dependency if you add the output of a source set (or another task) to the inputs of your task. (Gradle adds meta information to the outputs of tasks to archive that.)